# Как исправить код из книги AByteofPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Читал AByteofPython и в этой книге находится код, который у меня не работает

```
import os 
import time 
# 1. Файлы и каталоги, которые необходимо скопировать, собираются в список. 
source = 'C:\\otcuda' 
# Заметьте, что для имён, содержащих пробелы, необходимо использовать 
# двойные кавычки внутри строки. 
# 2. Резервные копии должны храниться в основном каталоге резерва. 
target_dir = 'C:\\cuda' # Подставьте тот путь, который вы будете 
использовать. 
# 3. Файлы помещаются в zip-архив. 
# 4. Именем для zip-архива служит текущая дата и время. 
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip' 
# 5. Используем команду "zip" для помещения файлов в zip-архив 
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ' '.join(source)) 
# Запускаем создание резервной копии 

if os.system(zip_command) == 0: 
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target) 
else: 
    print('Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ')
```

Сама команда зип работает(проверял в командной строке). 
Хотел бы спросить, почему она постоянно выводит "Создание резервной копии НЕ УДАЛОСЬ", то есть не работает, и как это исправить?

Comment: Потому что условие не равно 0

Comment: Операционная система? что есть zip?

Comment: http://librerussia.github.io/python-3-rabota-s-zip-arkhivami-modul-zipfile.html

Answer (score 1):

Друг, попробуй вот этот путь target_dir = 'C:\cuda' на другой локальный диск переписать, думаю поможет. Например: 'D:\Backup'
Я в начале тоже мучился, думал что-то с zip, потом заметил, что ошибка скрылась в коде, не правильно указал конечный путь.
Соответственно если у тебя Локальный диск Е, то пиши на 'Е:\Backup'
Не знаю, влияет это или нет, но заранее создай папку, куда будет проложен путь Backup.
Надеюсь помог.